# How to return multiple strings from a MSSQL database in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I was using this piece of code until i realized it only returns one piece of information. What is the correct method to use to retrieve multiple items?

```
sqlconn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [Description] from [dbo].[Categories] ", sqlconn);
string result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Console.WriteLine(result);
sqlconn.Close();
```

I have this ready to take a part an Array i just cant find out how to get it to return an array.

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: you are saving your result to a string, save your result to a list so you can loop through the results. use var result

Comment: That fixes the second problem but the main issue is     ExecuteScalar() returns back only one item. I'm wondering is there  a different function i could call anyone is aware of?

Comment: There are many ways.   Look into `ExecuteReader()` first.

Comment: Thanks just figured it there , couldn't get it earlier for some reason thanks for the help though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExecuteReader will return multiple items but you need to use a while loop to break down the results.

```
sqlconn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [Description] from [dbo].[Categories] ", sqlconn);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
      Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
}
```

Comment: No need for `String.Format` here. You can simply use: `Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);`

Comment: Very true, just had it left in from what i was doing , Edited.